# Gridview Paging checkbox not assigning properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, paging

I have data in my `gridview` and a `pagesize = 2`. Also each row in gridview has a checbox for approve/reject.

If I checked 2 rows from 1st page and 2 rows from 2nd page, it only approves the last two page checked from the 2nd page. Why this happens I don't know. I want all the 4 records to get approved.

Below is my code which I wrote:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDisplayCMMData" runat="server" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" 
     CssClass="heavyTable table" EmptyDataText="No records to display"
     AllowPaging="true" PageSize="2" 
     OnPageIndexChanging="grdDisplayCMMData_PageIndexChanging">
    <Columns>                    
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SAP ID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSAP_ID_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SAP_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID OD CHANGE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID_OD_COUNTCHANGE_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID OD CHANGE DATE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID_OD_CHANGEDDATE_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RRH COUNT CHANGE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRRH_COUNTCHANGE_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RRH_COUNTCHANGE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RRH COUNT CHANGE DATE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRRH_CHANGEDDATE_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RRH_CHANGEDDATE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TENANCY COUNT CHANGE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTENANCY_COUNTCHANGE_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TENANCY COUNT CHANGE DATE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTENANCY_CHANGEDDATE_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="STATUS">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSTATUS_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("STATUS") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CREATED BY" Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCREATEDBY_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CREATED_BY") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve/Reject">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApprRejCMM" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>                
</asp:GridView>
```

C# code:

```
protected void btnApproveCMM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
            bool flgCMM = false;
            IPColoFields ObjIPColoFields = new App_Code.IPColoFields();
            List<IPColoBilling_BKP.App_Code.UMS.UMSGroupDetails> UMSGroupDetails = (List<IPColoBilling_BKP.App_Code.UMS.UMSGroupDetails>)Session["lstUMSGroupDetails"];

            Session["lstUMSGroupDetails"] = UMSGroupDetails;
            string strApprove = "";

            foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in grdDisplayCMMData.Rows)
            {
                var checkbox = gvrow.FindControl("chkApprRejCMM") as CheckBox;

                if (checkbox.Checked)
                {
                    flgCMM = true;

                    int Id = Convert.ToInt32((grdDisplayCMMData.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].FindControl("lblID_CMM") as Label).Text);

                    ObjIPColoFields.Unique_Id = Id;
                    ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_BY_ID = intCurrentGrpId;
                    ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_BY_NAME = strCurrentGrp;
                    ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_TO_ID = UMSGroupDetails[1].GroupID;
                    ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_TO_NAME = UMSGroupDetails[1].GroupName;
                    ObjIPColoFields.FCA_STATUS = "1";
                    ObjIPColoFields.LAST_UPDATED_BY = lblUserName.Text;
                    strApprove = CommonDB.Approve_IPCOLO_CMMLevel(ObjIPColoFields);
                }
            }

            BindCMMData();
            if (flgCMM == false)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please check atleast one row'); window.location ='IpColoDefault.aspx';", true);
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Record Approved successfully'); window.location ='IpColoDefault.aspx';", true);

            }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string strErrorMsg = ex.Message.ToString() + " " + "StackTrace :" + ex.StackTrace.ToString();
        CommonDB.WriteLog("ERROR:" + strErrorMsg, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IPCOLO_LOG"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Also see the paging code

```
protected void grdDisplayCMMData_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            BindCMMData();
            grdDisplayCMMData.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            grdDisplayCMMData.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strErrorMsg = ex.Message.ToString() + " " + "StackTrace :" + ex.StackTrace.ToString();
            CommonDB.WriteLog("ERROR:" + strErrorMsg, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IPCOLO_LOG"].ToString());
        }
}
```

Comment: Each time you do paging, you are losing the checkboxes from the previous page. I'd wager that if you checked some on pg1, then pg2, then went back to pg1, it would be unchecked.

Comment: @tgolisch : what did you exactly mean here?? Any link or how to make it work. Please suggest

Comment: I like a.bajorinas concept of storing it in the viewstate. I would recommend trying that on `PageIndexChanging`: save `checked` settings from the previous page, then load `checked` settings (if any) for the current page.  I would only call `BindCmmData()` on `form_load`. I might even add an extra column to that dataset to hold the `checked` state.

Comment: @tgolisch: okay, let me try and check it

Comment: @tgolisch: a.bajorinas logic worked for me. Discussed with him and resolved it. Thanks to u as well for your inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can think of 2 ways on how you can fix the problem.

- Change your on page event to show / hide items.

  Default grid view paging event fires a postback and rebinds the grid therefore, you can't access checkboxes on a previous page, they just "dissapear". Now, you could solve this, by loading the full grid and then setting the visibility of the items not in your defined page rage to invisible. But this becomes very taxing with huge data and I wouldn't recommend this solution.
- The second solution would be to save the checkboxes state, in lets say a `ViewState`

  This way, you should implement an `OnCheckedChanged` event for your checbox which would add / remove itself from the viewstate of checked indexes. Now you would also have to implement an `OnItemDataBound` event to render the checkbox state from your viewstate. The last step would be in your button click to loop over the viewstate and perform your logic on each item.

  ```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdDisplayCMMData" runat="server" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" 
      CssClass="heavyTable table" EmptyDataText="No records to display"
      AllowPaging="true" PageSize="2" 
      OnPageIndexChanging="grdDisplayCMMData_PageIndexChanging">
      OnItemDataBound="grdDisplayCMMData_OnItemDataBound"
      <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve/Reject">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApprRejCMM" runat="server" OnCheckedChange="chkApprRejCMM_OnCheckedChanged" />
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>

  protected void chkApprRejCMM_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if(ViewState["CheckedCheckboxes"] != null)
      {
          var CheckedCheckboxes = (List<int>)ViewState["CheckedCheckboxes"];
          var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
          var idLabel = (TextBox)checkbox.BindingContainer.FindControl("lblID_CMM");
          if(idLabel != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(idLabel.Text))
          {
              if(checkbox.Checked)
              {
                  if(!CheckedCheckboxes.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(idLabel.Text)))
                      CheckedCheckboxes.Add(Convert.ToInt32(idLabel.Text));
             }
              else
              {
                  if(CheckedCheckboxes.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(idLabel.Text)))
                      CheckedCheckboxes.Remove(Convert.ToInt32(idLabel.Text))
              }
          }
          ViewState["CheckedCheckboxes"] = CheckedCheckboxes; 
      }
  }

  protected void grdDisplayCMMData_OnItemDataBound(object sender, GridViewEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      { 
          if(ViewState["CheckedCheckboxes"] != null)
          {
              var CheckedCheckboxes = (List<int>)ViewState["CheckedCheckboxes"];
              var checkbox = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("lchkApprRejCMM");
              var idLabel = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("lblID_CMM");
              if(idLabel != null && checkbox != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(idLabel.Text))
              {
                     if(CheckedCheckboxes.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(idLabel.Text)))
                      checbox.Checked = true;
                  else
                      checbox.Checked = false;
              }
          }
      }
  }

  protected void YourButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if(ViewState["CheckedCheckboxes"] != null)
      {
          var CheckedCheckboxes = (List<int>)ViewState["CheckedCheckboxes"];
          foreach (var id in CheckedCheckboxes)
          {
             //perform logic with id
          }
      }
  }
  ```

EDIT 1: Some mistakes I left out by writing the code without the use of an IDE

Comment: your code has error here `if(idLabel != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(idLabel.Text))`

Comment: I am sorry, as i was unable to lint/test the code at the time, whats the error?

Comment: Sorry, I was unavailable for some time. And sorry on my part. My created `List` is of type `int` and the method I wrote is passing in a string to `Contains` the edited version should be `CheckedCheckboxes.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(idLabel.Text))` as I was writing this on the go without a linter, I let this to go through.